# Where Can I Find Dinoceros?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I know these guys are found in the Giant Steps area, but I can't get any to spawn.

I am looking in the southern area of the Giant Steps.  The parts that you can just walk to from either Castaway Cove or Al Mamoon.  Is there a particular spawn location?

Comment: Do you have the dragon? You need it to get on top of the plateaus where it spawns, north of Al Mamoon. It's a rare spawn and spawns are random. Loading up a game save will reset the spawns.

Comment: I believe that you can get him both regions, but you need the dragon to land on the plateaus, he's a big white dino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the Dragon it to get on top of the plateaus where it spawns, north of Al Mamoon. It's a rare spawn and the spawns are random. Loading up a game save will also reset the spawns.

I've found that the best way to check to see if Dinocerous has spawned is to fast travel to Al Mamoon and go north from the left tip of the pool behind the town to check the spawns up on the cliff. If there aren't any, fast travel back to Al Mamoon and repeat.